# Get a date PHP value inside of HTML form

Tags: php, forms

I created one HTML FORM where I intend to get some info to store in a database, most of the fields will be filled by the user, but I want one field (date) to appear filled right away with the current date, so I gave this value

```
<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>
```

to the FORM field:

```
<input name="date" type="hidden" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>">
```

Then I tested it, and instead of get a date on the Database I just get the PHP code.

All this is applicable to one project school, that is the creation of one blog.
And right now I intend that the comments FORM created for users store the time/date that the comment was made.

Is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: Is PHP enabled on your server?

Comment: If your form filename is `.html`, your web server won't process it as PHP.  Make sure it is `.php`.

Comment: Are you sure your server is properly configured to serve php code?  What is the extension of the file with the form?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. The filename already is in .php.
Thank you for the warning :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a simple solution, insert it direct in the SQL code.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO blog SET date=now()";
```

Comment: But it doesn't address the underlying issue?

Comment: Why don't you stock the timestamp of the date ? So when you'll display the date on your application, you'll be able to print it like 'd/m/Y' or 'Y/m/d' for example

Comment: Why do you insert current time like that when you can use a build in value like `now()` for instance?

Comment: I gave him a simple solution that was similar to his own code, giving him an answer and a solution to their problem. This can be done in several different ways, I'm just trying to be helpfull and kind :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save this date in your database you must change the date format,

```
$date = preg_replace( "/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})/i", "$3-$2-$1", $_POST['date']);
```

and you save $date in your database